# Generated APK size increased in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I switched my IDE from eclipse to android studio and generated apk after some very minor changes (No class or files were added).
The APK generated from eclipse was around of size 3 MB but when I generated APK from android studio, the apk size was around 5.5 MB.
I even tried to clean and generate APK in Release mode but still APK size was same i.e. 5.5 MB.
Is there any specific reason behind this in android studio or am I missing something ?

Comment: can you paste your build.gradle?

Comment: I wonder if Proguard is being run with the same options under Android Studio?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.jaipurmetro"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
}

Answer (score 3):

your problem certainly have nothing to do with Android Studio or Eclipse. It's todo with `Gradle` and `Ant`. Those are the built systems used by each respectively.

On a general approach it seems to be that the `Ant` build was using `ProGuard` to remove unused resources and classes whilst your `build.gradle` file is not instructing `Gradle` to do the same.

Trying adding the `minifyEnabled` to your release build, like in the example below.

PS: change the name of the proguard file to the one on your project

```
buildTypes {
   release {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
   }
}
```

Comment: "Generate signed APK: Errors while building apk".  Its giving Exception Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: app\proguard-rules.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Read the answer again.